# Windows CE Form bug

Tags: c#, winforms, compact-framework

I'm developing WinForm applications to Windows CE device. I have got a bug, on the top of the form(all form) have a 20 px height and full width zone, with topmost behaviour and Control color background, with cursor. On Visual Studio design mode can't see it just only on the device. Question is how to disappear it?
Thanks a lot

Comment: A screenshot and some code to support your question would be good to see.

Comment: Yes, same as Alex. Need screenshot and code. I assume you are talking about the Taskbar on windows mobile or the title bar on Windows ce. But without details about your target and hardware device?!? See http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2012/05/29/windows-mobile-kiosk-mode-series-part-2/ for details about taskbar.

Comment: Screenshot--> tinypic.com/r/2j62xhk/9 On empty Form does the same behaviour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm willing to be that what you have there is a MainMenu with no MenuItems in it.  It will show up as a blank strip across the top of the Form and cover any UI elements, but it won't show up in the designer.

Comment: I run into this every single time I start a new project. By default such an empty menu is created "for you", all you have to do is remove the value for `Menu` it in the properties of your form in the designer.